# How to use printf in NS-2

Tags: c++, ns2

I am trying to modify the NS-2 core code by adding a simple `printf` statement in the function `Mac802_11::command`. However, no matter how many times I add the line of code (`printf("hello there!\n");`) and then execute `./install`, nothing comes up.

Is there any other requirement before the text is displayed? By the way, I am making use of NS-2.34 on an Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: You do build it before installing it?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is in the C++ part, not the Tcl part; I'll retag accordingly…

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, so I do have to manually build ns-2.34 first before executing my code? I have added #ifdef DEBUG for the printfs they are displayed now but only when the code runs under gdb.

Comment: @DonalFellows, yes the C++ part but I was sure if it could have something to do with calling Tcl functions from C++? Still, thanks.

Comment: Still don't see that this has anything to do with Tcl.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ns2.34 directory where your Makefile is located. Issue a make after you have made changes to the existing .cc file. Do NOT issue install.

ns-2.34$make

Comment: I have already done so. However, the same problem persists. Does it make a difference if I use gcc/g++ 4.5 instead of gcc/g++ 4.4?